# Credit card auto fill not working on React

Tags: reactjs, credit-card, autofill

I am trying to set credit card auto fill up and running.

The idea is: open the following link on a device (I have an iPhone 6).

https://codesandbox.io/s/1v6lrjo324

If theres data on the device, on clicking on the first field it should show a message above the keyboard saying something like: "fill credit card automatically". This is a success.

Now create the simplest create-react-app and paste the code above on your index.js or App.js and open it on your device. This is a fail.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it's not clear what you expect. It showes me a 3 column box with no data and it seems pretty much what's in the project....

Comment: Ive updated the explanation

Answer (score -1):

Create react app is not the right instrument.

I suggest you tu build your test using

[create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)

Comment: Why? I want this to work on mobile web, not on an app.

Comment: this project is made for mobile environment, completely opposite to react-app standard which is oriented to desktop only solutions.